# Access Wordpress query by index number outside the loop

Tags: wp-query

In wordpress query, Can I single out the specific post by index number of the query  result?

for example

```
<?php 
            $args =  array( 
                'post_type' => 'headimages',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
             $package_query = new WP_Query( $args );
             $num = $package_query->post_count; ?>
```

so how do i display the second result or third result from this query? Can I do something like this?

```
<php $thirdresult = $package_query[2];>
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of a query are stored as an array in the `$posts` property of the query object, so you can access the third result like so:

```
$package_query = new WP_Query( $args )
$third_result  = $package_query->posts[2];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching the net like three hours for this simple solution. You just saved my life. Thanks again.